# Is is there any way to access windows login screen and Add custum ui on the Login screen on Windows10?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-dev-center

Basically I want to create a link "Reset password" on windows login screen. upon click it should open a popup and ask security questions.
And the point is is there any way to access windows login screen and create UI which I discussed above.
OS is Windows 10
Many thanks in advance.

I have done research on GINA DLL but it is for only windows Xp.
And I found that COM Objects will helpful but I am not really sure, as I am not an .Net developer.

Comment: No. You can see this yourself. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> and the screen goes into a sort of UAC mode where you can't sed any commands to Change Password. To do this properly requires really low level code, also it might not even be possible anymore with Win10.

Answer (score 0):

It is now done with [Credential Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows) 
, mainly the [ICredentialProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nn-credentialprovider-icredentialprovider) interface

You can find a sample in the SDK  :
[V2 Credential Provider Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CredentialProvider)

or like :
 [Custom Credential Provider for Password Reset](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/aho/2009/11/14/custom-credential-provider-for-password-reset/)

or [CredProvider.NET (A Windows Credential Provider written in C#)](https://github.com/SteveSyfuhs/CredProvider.NET)